# Convert from Unix time to YYYY-MM-DD in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

if there is a function to or a way to convert from UNIX time to YYYY-MM-DD in BigQuery syntax ?

Comment: Yes, it appears there is. Did you [look at the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=ja#datetimefunctions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have stored timestamp then you can get the UTC format by running below query

```
SELECT FORMAT_UTC_USEC((INTEGER(your_timestamp_field)+19800)*1000000)
```

Comment: could you explain the 19800? I don't understand it :/

Comment: 19800 seconds = 5.30 hours. I had to store the time in IST zone hence the addtition of 19800 secs.

Answer (score 3):

The newer "standard SQL" syntax has [a set of functions for timestamp operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp-functions).  That includes [`timestamp_seconds`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds), which converts unixtime (in seconds - there's another function for milliseconds) to a timestamp:

```
select timestamp_seconds(time) from <your-table>
```

If you want to format that in a particular way, you can convert that to a formatted string with [`format_timestamp`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_timestamp).  For instance, for your YYYY-MM-DD:

```
select format_timestamp("%Y-%m-%d", timestamp_seconds(time)) from <your-table>
```